# how to insert child table first, then parent table in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

i tried to insert the transactions_detail first then get the total_cost at transactions table.

```
transactions_detail
detail_id, product_id, transactions_id, product_quantity
```

```
transactions
transactions_id, user_id, total_price, transactions_date
```

how so that when the transactions_detail table is inserted, id_transactions is null first, then if the transaction table is filled in, then the id_transactions between the two tables match

Comment: Why did you want to that? insert the parent table after insert the child table.

Comment: One of the reasons of referential integrity, is to protect against programming errors like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in MySQL.

To temporarily break a referential constraint you'll need the database engine to implement "deferrable constraints" and unfortunately MySQL does not implement this *standard SQL feature*.

You would need to switch the database engine to PostgreSQL or Oracle to do this.

In any case, the constraint can be invalid for the duration of a transaction only. At the moment when the `COMMIT` is issued in the transaction, all constraints must be valid. This seems to be your use case.